# Estimote iOS SDK Examples cannot find beacons to select

Tags: ios, bluetooth, estimote

I have the Estimote iOS SDK downloaded and running on the iPhone with no errors. However, when I click into the 3 examples, it goes to the 'Select Beacon' page and none appear to click. I know that my Esimotes are working since I have another app accessing them. Is there something that I need to do to get the beacons to appear on the list?  Both the bluetooth and location services are on with the phone.

Using :
Estimote
iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1.0
XCode 5.1.1

Comment: Did you try to run application on several devices at the same time? I guess that you see empty list because there are no any beacons near you. But iPhone 4s and later could work as beacon.

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly, I had to turn the phone off and on again. Here is a post I found on the community forum.

https://community.estimote.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200875653-Unable-to-see-Beacons-on-the-Proximity-Demo-App?locale=en-us

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your own answer, the best solution for now is to simply reboot your phone. The problem is caused by a bug in iOS 7.1 Bluetooth stack. It most often causes problems with CoreLocation, sometimes also with CoreBluetooth. We're still waiting for Apple to fix this.

Cheers.